# Cannot scrape the next web page after clicking

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs, puppeteer

I am trying to write a script through phantomjs to scrape a table split in different pages (currently two but could be more or less in the future) of a website.

I have managed to produce two html outputs with the content I need however the output produced is always the first table and never the second. I have tried including a timeout to wait for the page to load but it does not seem to work. I have tested the clicking of the next button on Chrome console and it works. 
Not sure what is still missing...

```
// Step 1: Open web page
var page = require('webpage').create();
var fs = require('fs');
function onPageReady() {
page.open('https://adb.taleo.net/careersection/1/jobsearch.ftl#');
phantom.waitFor(function() {return !page.loading;});

// Step 2: Scrape first table
var htmlContent = page.evaluate(function() {
    return document.documentElement.outerHTML;});
fs.write('C://MY_PATH' + '/outputadb.html', 
htmlContent,'w')

// Step 3: Click on button and wait for it to show
page.evaluate(function() { $("a#next").click(); });
phantom.waitFor(function() {
    return page.evaluate(function() {return $(".result-list- 
button").is(":visible");});
});
var htmlContent2 = page.evaluate(function() {
    return document.documentElement.outerHTML;});
fs.write('C://MY_PATH' + 
 '/outputadb2.html', htmlContent2,'w')
//console.log('READY!');
 phantom.exit();
}

phantom.waitFor = function(callback) {
  do {
   // Clear the event queue while waiting.
   // This can be accomplished using page.sendEvent()
   this.page.sendEvent('mousemove');
  } while (!callback());
 }

 onPageReady();
```

Following the suggestions I have tried to use puppeteer. 
Here below my try however, I am getting object promise as output instead of the html source code. Any ideas why?

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs');

(async function main() {

try {
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true});
const page = await browser.newPage();
page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36')
await page.goto('https://adb.taleo.net/careersection/2/jobsearch.ftl#', { 
waitUntil: "networkidle2" });
await page.waitFor(1 * 1000);

const htmlContent =  page.evaluate(() => {
return document.documentElement.innerHTML})
body.innerHTML, bodyHandle);
console.log(htmlContent);
fs.writeFileSync("out.html", htmlContent);

await browser.close();
} catch (e) {
    console.log('our error',e)
}

})();
```

Comment: You might want to switch to puppeteer, not many are answering phantomjs questions these days.

Comment: @pguardiario thank you for the comment. I have now tried to implement puppeteer but being a newbie I am stuck at obtaining only an object promise as output instead of the html code. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concerning your puppeteer code: you need to `await` all operations that work with puppeteer, e.g.

```
const htmlContent = await page.evaluate()
```

Comment: Great! Thank you very much @Vaviloff